# Predict future with models / VSM /decision tree/ linear regression/ Artificial Neural Networks

Tags: python-3.x

I need to choose the best model to predict the traffic in a determinated hour.
I think cluster is not for this problme, but i still don't know what would be the best option. If it's vector machine, decision tree, linear regression or Artificial Neural Networks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends mostly on your data. How much data do you have? If you only have few examples, I would go with VSM (Assuming you mean Support Vector Machines?). If you have a lot of examples I personally would go with a neural network.
I guess you could even get a nice representation of the prolem if you use a recurrent network.